# How I can split config file to many files?

Tags: linux, configuration, nfs

I have got config in `/etc/exports`. I want to see another file as a config too for it, for example `/etc/my_exports`. How I can do it? What I need to write in `/etc/exports` to see `/etc/my_exports` like continue of config file?

Comment: You can't. What is it you are really trying to do? Why would you want a separate config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your os. On my fedora 21 the man page for `exportfs` says it also reads all files in directory `/etc/exports.d/`.